# URL not changed using servlet

Tags: servlets

I have problem of not getting URL changed after servlet code successfully,
It is still showing servlet URL.I am using

RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
                rd.forward(request,response);

but it isn't going to  change URL in addressbar

Comment: forward doesn't change the URL, but redirect does.

Comment: You might need to use redirect if you want this to be seen in browser.

Comment: Thanks I get it change url from addressbar using redirect.